# Reverse each line in triangle number

Tags: c++

I have managed to make a triangle like this 
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5

but how to create triangle like this?
1 
2 1 
3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1

My code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=5,y=1;
    
    while (y<=x)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=y; i++)
        {

            cout<<i<<' ';
        }
        y++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Count down from y to 1 instead of counting up from 1 to y: [https://ideone.com/qUzSkl](https://ideone.com/qUzSkl)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to reverse the `for` loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=5,y=1;
    
    while (y<=x)
    {
        for(int i=y; i>=1; i--)
        {
    
            cout<<i<<' ';
        }
        y++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```